# Derived length in linear groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, solvable-groups

If $G$ is a group let $(G^{(m)})_{m \geq 0}$ be the derived series.
If there is some $m$ such that $G^{(m+1)} = G^{(m)}$, call the smallest such $m$ the *derived length* of $G$.
I am interested in conditions which control the derived length of finitely generated $G \leq \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$, where $K$ is an arbitrary field. Here are a couple.

1. If $G$ is actually soluble, then the derived length is bounded in terms of $n$. This was proved by Zassenhaus and sharpened by Newman and others. The sharp bound has the form $O(\log n)$.
2. Suppose $G$ is finite. Let $P$ be the last term in the derived series. Then any minimal subgroup $S \leq G$ such that $G = PS$ must be soluble, and $G^{(m)} \leq P S^{(m)}$ for each $m$. By 1 this implies that $P = G^{(m)}$ for some $m  = O(\log n)$.

On the other hand, any nonabelian free group has infinite derived length, and there are nonabelian free subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$.

Here are a couple specific questions, to make my question concrete. Let $G \leq \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ be finitely generated.

1. If $G$ has finite derived length (aka perfect-by-soluble), must its derived length be bounded in terms of $n$?
2. If $G$ is soluble-by-perfect, same question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you assume about $G$ in the question as you first discuss various assumptions (and Question 1 seems better motivated, while in Question 2 it seems to boil down to solvable groups).

Comment: I assume $G$ is finitely generated and contained in $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$.

Comment: So Q2 is already answered, you'd better stick to Q1?

Comment: How is Q2 answered? I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: It's unclear to me that information about the soluble factor on the bottom translates to information about the soluble factor on the top, but maybe I am being thick.

Comment: Oops, indeed you're right.